# asp vbscript soap call add header

Tags: soap, vbscript, asp-classic

i need to make a soap wsdl call which i do as follows:

```
dim soap
    Set soap = CreateObject("MSSOAP.SoapClient30")
    soap.ClientProperty("ServerHTTPRequest") = True
    Call soap.MSSoapInit( "http://10.0.0.1:8080/Logon?wsdl", "Logon")
     soap.ConnectorProperty("Timeout") = 90000
          result = soap.getAuthorization(id)
```

I need to add a wssecurity header, does anyone know how i can go about it, i have the header i need to send i just donno how to attach it.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

[VB6 Code](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-ejbsoap/index.html)